# How can we hide the tableHeaderView and tableFooterView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have  two buttons which i add it in one in table-footer and other one in table-header,i know how to hide the headerview of the table using this code`table.tableHeaderView.hidden = YES;`
but the problem is there is still space in the top portion of the table.That space is equal to the header-view size,but the view is hidden .It still has the space.How can we disable the table-header by removing this space.I hope you genius developers understand my question.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Instead of hiding the header view you should do,

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
```

And later if you want to show it then just assign it again,

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView;
```

---

In Swift:

```
class myTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableHeaderView: UIView!

    private func toggleHeaderView() {
        if tableView.tableHeaderView == nil {
            tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView 
        } else { 
            tableView.tableHeaderView = nil 
        }
    }

}
```

on your Storyboard, simply drag a UIView in to the table view. It will "magically" become the table view header (if you do another one, it will become the table view footer). **HOWEVER** you must **click on** that header view, and **drag** the referencing outlet **to the table view controller**, and link it to "tableHeaderView" ... that part is not "magic".

Note that because of the "!" in the declaration, you have to remember to drag the link on Storyboard or you'll get a runtime error during testing, so that's a good thing.

Comment: You should assign the view again. See my updated answer, Sir ;-)

Comment: When using ARC, make sure to declare 'theHeaderView' as 'strong' like so: @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *theHeaderView; Otherwise, it will get released and set to nil which will cause the 'show' code above to fail.

Comment: Daniel, you saved me. I had a weak IBOutlet and my view got released all the time.. could not figure it out.

Comment: I can hide it, but it doesn't appear when I reassign view to headerView property. View is not nil. How can I fix that?

Comment: @dig Have you got any solution? I am facing same problem

Comment: @jalakpatel Yes I had issues with navigation. I was setting UIView to table.tableHeaderView of controller A, while the app was showing another instance of controller A, which looked same as original instance.

Comment: When I set tableHeaderView to nil there is still a blank space at the top.

Comment: I don't recommend linking the tableHeaderView in storyboard to your local headerHolder as an outlet.  If you do that, and the tableHeaderView has any other views in it connected as outlets, they will become nil when you set tableView.tableHeaderView to nil.   Instead, just create a local variable to store headerHolder, and in viewDidLoad, do headerHolder = tableView.tableHeaderView

Comment: @Harris they become null because when you link to the storyboard a "weak" reference is created. You have to remove the "weak" keyword for your controller to keep a hold of it.

Comment: @Daniel: Your comment helped me more than this answer. Strong reference is what I was missing and getting issue with toggling headerView all the time. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks ! Just what i needed !

Comment: @bugloaf did you find a solution to reasign the searchbar back to the tableViewHeader? Im with the same problem

Comment: @NathanBarreto Sorry, I don't remember.

Comment: try this.
tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = CGRect.zero

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView?.removeFromSuperview()
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Set an UIView with height as CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude instead of '0'.
This will remove the blank space appearing at the top after removing the tableViewHeader.
This worked for me.

Comment: On ObjetiveC, use `CGFLOAT_MIN` instead of `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude`

Comment: when I make **tableView.tableHeaderView = nil** it caused layout errors. Your answer helped me, thanks!

Comment: `tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: .zero)`

Answer (score 6):

If you created your view in storyboard, you can hide it temporary with

`tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = CGRect.zero`

To display it again, use

`tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50)`

Answer (score 4):

```
[self.tableView.tableHeaderView removeFromSuperview];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
//hidden sectionFooter

- (nullable UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nil;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:    (NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: I disagree in this instance. The code is self explanatory and this is a correct answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the correct answer as the question concerned the tableHeaderView. The answer is in regards to the section headers and footers, which is something completely different.

Answer (score 3):

removeFromSuperview  or set nil not work when "reloadData"

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.001f)];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

Often a ghost header view will continue to appear after a header view has been set using a "viewForHeaderInSection" and is later programmatically hidden or set to nil.  To make it go away completely explicitly set the sectionHeaderHeight = 0.

Objective C:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) section
{
    if (self.viewMode == SectionHeaderShouldBeHidden)
    {
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0;
        return nil;
    }
    else if (self.viewMode == SectionHeaderShouldAppear)
    {
        //section text as a label
        UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        lbl.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
        lbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [lbl setBackgroundColor:App.secondaryColor];
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 20;

        if (self.queryResultsViewModel.items.count == 0)
            return lbl;

        lbl.text = @"Section Header Text";

        return lbl;
    }
}
```

Swift 4+:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if !self.viewMode == HeaderShouldBeShown
    {
        self.listView.sectionHeaderHeight = 0
        return nil
    }

    let lbl: UILabel = UILabel.init()
    lbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    lbl.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
    lbl.textColor = UIColor.white
    lbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 20
    lbl.text = "Section Header Text"
    return lbl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if tableView.tableHeaderView == nil{ 
tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerHolder 
}
else
{
 tableView.tableHeaderView = nil 
}
}
```

You should create an outlet headerHolder & its must be a strong property. If we used a weak property for headerHolder, once it is nil, it is released & you cant set it again as header