# SearchBar controller set position after tableview scrolling in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar

[image]

Tableview With `searchBarController` reference of 
https://blog.apoorvmote.com/add-uisearchcontroller-to-tableview/
working.

I'll Add search Button for show/hide the search controller. If I can scroll tableview after click the search button at navigation bar show searchController at custom position. After search Button click it should hide from the custom position.

Please, help me

Comment: add screenshot which display problem .

Comment: brother this is your computer path . it is not accessible .

Comment: if I can scroll tableview upto header after I can click the search button at that position search controller show there

Comment: navigation button code  @IBAction func NAVSearchButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
   launchBool = !launchBool
 }

Comment: this hide and show code of search controller 
    var launchBool: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if launchBool == true {
                
                Status = 1
                tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
                       let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
                   self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
               
                
            } else {
                
                   tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
                   myInt = 0 }}}

Comment: if I click the search button it showing at tableview header position,but I need custom position at tableview

Comment: custom postion means where ?

Comment: tableview header position

Comment: if I did with my code but when tableview scrolling after its not showing at tableview header position I try  var launchBool: Bool = false { didSet { if launchBool == true { Status = 1 tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true) } else { tableView.tableHeaderView = nil myInt = 0 }}}

Comment: my aim is after tableview scrolling after search button click it has to show at the tableview header position pls help me bro

Comment: see for how to hide and show header i think actually problem occurred due to this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079933/3901620

Comment: it's not working bro