# How to remove animation when show/hide a UIStackView?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview, stackview

Whenever the `UIStackView` is shown or hidden, the hiding and revealing parts are animated. Is it possible to remove animation on it altogether. Like it just appears and disappears. Thank you.

the current hierarchy looks like this ==> `UITableView` > table header `UIView` > `UIStackView` > `UIView` with header label `UILabel`. I'm trying to hide and show the table header.

code that I have tried so far...

- `headerView.frame.size.height = 0` - does not work since the contents of stack view is still shown
- `stackView.isHidden = true` - still shows the blank header view which I want to be hidden
- `headerLabel.isHidden = true` - same as above point, blank header view is still shown

Comment: Can you update your post with some code which you did so far!

Comment: UIStackView shown or hidden or is it views in the stack view?

Comment: @AuRis - the current hierarchy looks like this ==> `UITableView` > table header `UIView` > `UIStackView` > `UIView` with header label `UILabel`. I'm trying to hide and show the table header itself.

Comment: @Tuhin post updated with three approaches I have tried so far.

Comment: If you want to hide table view header you do that by implementing table view's data source, in your case return `nil` in `viewForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: @AuRis I believe you are referring to section header. I'm referring to the tableViewHeaderFooter. The view added on top of prototype cells.

Comment: Then set your `tableView.tableHeaderView = nil` and reload your tableview by doing `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: I think this is your answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079820/how-can-we-hide-the-tableheaderview-and-tablefooterview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079820/how-can-we-hide-the-tableheaderview-and-tablefooterview)